# How to put .HAR file exported from Chrome to import into JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, har

I export all the network calls from chrome to an hAR file format which I again want to import into JMeter to use the network call for load testing.

How can I do it? 
I have heard about floor.io, it isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use online [Blazemeter converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/), just upload file and convert (limited to 50M)

> Acceptable files: .json, .har, .xml, .pcap

For large files use [HAR to Apache JMeter Convertor](https://seitenbau.github.io/har2JMeter/)

> ```
> har2JMeter -har [*.har] -jmx [*.jmx]
> ```

Download zip currently unavailable, so you need to download github project and run

```
gradlew distZip
```

Then open zip file in build/distributions/har2JMeter-master-0.4.0.SNAPSHOT

You will have execution file in bin folder

Comment: But it doesnt accepts the file which is more than 50M. My har file is around 200 MB

Comment: yea, that is what I was looking at. But from where and how do I download and run the same?

Comment: I am getting this below error:
FAILURE: Build aborted because of an internal error.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '11.0.3'.

Comment: @Tarun it's a gradle - java compatibility issue, please ask a new question with gradle and java version (or search online first)

Answer (score -3):

I created a tool to convert a HAR file to a JMeter script and the record.xml file.

I wrote an article on the dzone site in the testing zone about the reasons for creating this tool and also a short **user manual**:
https://dzone.com/articles/convert-a-har-file-to-jmeter-script

This tool is a plugin for JMeter, the name of this plugin is "vdn@github - har-convertor-jmeter-tool"

Link to this project :
[har-convertor-jmeter-tool project](https://github.com/vdaburon/har-convertor-jmeter-plugin)

Some features :

- Run locally on your coomputer
- create page (Transaction Controller) when time between 2 URLs is more then N ms
- Add Pause between Pages
- Regular expression matches for filter Include URL
- Regular expression matches for filter Exclude URL
- Remove cookie in http header because add a Cookie Manager
- Remove cache header in the http request because add a Cache Manager
- Create a Record.xml that contains exchanges, useful for future correlation
- Numbering page
- Numbering http sampler name
- Apache License, Version 2.0
- Load the generated script